# Maintainable Conversions

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a class that inherits from a base class; it is almost exactly the same, the difference is a TypeParam to help with intellisense. I want to provide a way to convert an existing parent class to the child class.

I am currently doing it this way:

```
class A
{
   public int f1;
   public int f2;
}

class B<T> : A
{
   public static B<T> Create(A a)
   {
       return new B<T>
       {
           f1 = a.f1;
           f2 = a.f2;
       };
   }
}
```

My concern is that this is not a very maintainable solution, and could cause problems if new fields or properties are added but forgotten in the create method. I also would like to avoid reflection just to copy an object.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you looking for mapper? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286294/object-to-object-mapper

Comment: This isn't casting, it's conversion.  The two are *very* different.  You need to be careful with your terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical way is to provide a copy constructor within each class in the hierarchy. For example:

```
class A
{
    private int f1;
    private int f2;

    public A()
    {
       ...
    }

    public A(A original)
    {
        f1 = original.f1;
        f2 = original.f2;
    }
}

class B<T> : A
{
    public B(A original) : base(original)
    {
    }

    // Possibly overload with a B(B<T> original) as well?
}
```

That way the copying happens in the class which declares the fields. It is best-placed to know how to handle those fields; it definitely has *access* to the fields even if they're private; when a new field is introduced, you only have to make a change in the same class rather than derived classes.

It's still somewhat ugly, and I'd avoid it if possible - but that depends on the context. (Sometimes using composition instead of inheritance is the way forwards, but that's certainly not universally true.)

Comment: Jon, this is very much a better approach as like you said, the more appropriate place is the declaring object. But it still has the same problem of potentially forgetting when adding a new field.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer: Yes, it does - which is one reason I'd avoid it if possible. You may be able to spot that with clever reflection-based unit tests, potentially... but so long as you use the pattern sparingly, it shouldn't be too hard to just be disciplined about it. (There are also reflection-based tools to do this automatically, but whether or not they're suitable for you depends on your context.)